# How to Combine Array String As Keys And Number As Value In Php

Tags: php

I have a problem to do the combining between 2 arrays.

In the first array as a string (example array data):

```
Array
(
    [0] => courses
    [1] => courses
    [2] => courses
    [3] => courses
    [4] => courses
)
```

Second array as a value (Example Array values):

```
Array
(
    [0] => 64
    [1] => 63
    [2] => 62
    [3] => 2
    [4] => 9
)
```

After I tried to combine between 2 arrays like this:

$combine = (array_combine($data, $courses))

I can only get a combination result like this:

```
Array
(
    [courses] => 9
)
```

How can i get the result of combination between the two arrays above, like this?

```
Array
(
    [courses] => 64
    [courses] => 63
    [courses] => 62
    [courses] => 2
    [courses] => 9
)
```

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: You can only have one unique key, that's why there is only one element in the resulting array. For example, if you could get the result you want what would `$combine['courses']` return?

Comment: I understand now. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

You are not able to generate your intended output as you can't have multiple of the same key in an array. This is why you are ending up with one entry of 'courses'.

For example this would be do-able:

```
Array
(
    [courses] => array(
        [0] => 63
        [1] => 63
        [2] => 62
        [3] => 2
        [4] => 9
    )
)
```

You need to change your approach.

Comment: I understand now. Thank you in advance